# How can I add variable as text annotation into convert option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to insert **UserProfile.nickname** as text annotation into convert option.
This is what I have now.
How can I fix this?

**user_profile.rb**

```
before_save :text_to_insert

def text_to_insert
    nickname = self.nickname 
end

has_attached_file :user_avatar,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }, 
     :convert_options => {
      :small => lambda {|a| %Q{ -gravity south  -pointsize 25 -fill black -annotate +0+0 "#{nickname}" -fill white -annotate +2+2 "#{nickname} "} } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try #{:nickname}  or maybe #{self.nickname} instead.

I'm with same problem.
Usually they recomend you to create a custom paperclip processor to do it, but years ago i done something like that in a way which remembers the one o mentioned in your question, but i dont remember exactly how.

If you accomplished, please post your solution here and Let me know if works ;)